# is it necessary to use htmlspecialchars in laravel controller when request is get

Tags: php, laravel, security, laravel-5

I use laravel 5.5 for my projects I have an ajax for my shopping cart that send a get request to server for saving a product in cart . My question is Should I use htmlspecialchars function for my request parameters to prevent from hack
Shall I do anything to remove request from special characters

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is for output, eg to HTML to a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer in short **'NO'**, Maintain your cart data in session unless it needs to retain for later use. Always use binding so you do not have to do extra work or long dirty code.

In Laravel binding can be done easily like this

```
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->productId = $request->productId;
$cart->userId = $user->id;
$cart->actualPrice = $product->actualPrice;
$cart->price = $request->price;
$cart->save();
```

It will do the magic for you.